# Rich client web application project structure using backbone.js framework and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js

We have a rich client web application which uses Backbone.js framework for client side and Spring MVC for server side. We have different java components, each as a separate project in the business tier which are used by the web application. we are planning to use maven for build. We are thinking of following directory structure for the same.

```
sampleproject
|
|---src
|   |
|   |---main
|   |   |       
|   |   |--java
|   |   |--resources
|   |
|   |---test
|   |   |
|   |   |--java
|   |   |--resources
|   |
|   |---webapp
|   |   |
|   |   |--resources
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |--framework
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |--controllers
|   |   |   |   |--css
|   |   |   |   |--font
|   |   |   |   |--js
|   |   |   |   |--models
|   |   |   |   |--templates
|   |   |   |   |--views
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |--module
|   |   |
|   |   |--WEB-INF
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |--classes
|   |   |   |--spring
|   |   |   |--views
|   |   |   |--web.xml
|
|---target
|---pom.xml
```

Also, we are thinking to separate out the javascript implementation of web application to a separate project(Inside the webapp/resources/framework folder).

1.Is there any standard project structure defined for such projects or if there is a better structure that can be followed?

2.Are there any standard principles/rules that project structure should adhere to?